# Password obtained accurately without satisfying the regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a concern with the Regex detailed as following

```
/^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.+[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:;&gt;.&lt;;,]).{1,}$/
```

I have used this Regex for password policy i.e. as following

- At Least 1 Upper Case Character[A-Z]
- At Least 1 Lower Case Character[a-z]
- At Least 1 Special Character[!@#$%^]
- At Least 1 Digit[0-9]
- Minimum 8 Characters

But whenever I tested it the pattern goes wrong. For example, in this kind of inputs like

> Ex:
>
> James1234
>
> jam123Es
>
> 1234James
>
> 1234jaMeS

In these, all the above examples I had not applied any special character, Instead of it is Satisfying the Regex.

Comment: I think your regex got hit with an HTML escaper. &amp means 'a' or 'm' or....etc

Comment: @zzxyz I Had also tried by removing this one but still it is not working

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't answer your actual question but others have already answered that, so I thought I would share my thoughts anyway.

In my opinion there are a few downsides to a single regular expression like this, it's difficult to read and debug. Also there is no way to tell which of the rules actually made the check fail.
You could consider breaking it down into smaller checks, which will also make it easy to add additional rules later on.

```
<?php
$check = function (string $p): string
{
    if (strlen($p) < 8) {
        return "Not long enough";
    }

    if (!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $p)) {
        return "No upper case character";
    }

    if (!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $p)) {
        return "No lower case character";
    }

    if (!preg_match('/\d/', $p)) {
        return "No digits";
    }

    if (!preg_match('/[!@#$%^]/', $p)) {
        return "No special character";
    }


    return "OK";
};
```

Comment: You could even give each of these regexes a name, give each field an array of the correct ones, and have one function do all the validation

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you haven't used '\' before the reserved characters in the regex.
For eg : `( )` are all reserved and hence you need a `\` before them in the regex.

And the use of `.{1,}$` is not required.

This might solve the issue though I haven't used all the special characters you require.

`/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/`

Comment: I don't think they need to be escaped inside []

Comment: @Boo It is working for me, could u please tell me what the changes i have to do in your suggested code for not allowing space or tab

Comment: @NaveenK.Sanadhya sorry fot the late reply. But to avoid white spaces add `\S*$` at the end of the regex so : 
`/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})\S*$/`

Comment: @zzxyz It didn't work for me in my browser console for some weird reason :/ So I just thought it might be the reason.